# Как выполнить команды базы в скрипте bash?

Tags: bash

вот допустим у меня есть вот эти команды

```
sudo mysql
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET plugin='' WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT;
sudo mysql -u root -p
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSS';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT;
```

Как мне их правильно написать в скрипте bash, вот пример

```
        log_n "${BLUE}Настраиваем базу-данных"

        sudo mysql
        USE mysql;
        UPDATE user SET plugin='' WHERE user='root';
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
        EXIT;
        sudo mysql -u root -p
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSS';
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
        EXIT;
        
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "${green}[SUCCESS]"
            tput sgr0
        else
            echo "${red}[ERROR]"
            tput sgr0
            exit
        fi
```

Comment: Посмотрите на [here documents](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/zoneminder вот тут есть пример, как раз с mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Так и написать. Просто скопируй команды и вставь в место, где они должны исполняться. Единственное - нужно убрать sudo из команд и запускать файл с командами от имени суперпользователя.

P.S. Помимо этого надо указать в первой строчке путь к интерпретатору bash, так что в первую строку вставь #!/usr/bin/bash.

Comment: А можешь кинуть пример пожалуйста? не очень понял

Comment: Я сам-то не до конца понял, что ты имеешь ввиду. Первый кусок кода это команды? А второй кусок кода это уже существующий скрипт Bash?

Comment: Вот смотри, есть допустим вот такой пример 

  log_n "${BLUE}Установка подкомпонентов #6"
  apt -y install screen > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "${green}[SUCCESS]"
   tput sgr0
  else
   echo "${red}[ERROR]"
   tput sgr0
   exit
  fi

он выполняет команду установку screen, мне нужно что то такое, только для команды с базой (которые я оставил выше)

Comment: Просто как выполнить эти все запросы скриптом bash ? Что бы я ничего сам не нажимал там, чисто автоматически

Comment: То есть нужно создать файл, который бы при запуске выполнял команды из первого твоего блока с кодом? Прости, просто реально непонятна сама проблема.

Comment: По сути так оно и есть, только это должен быть .sh файл 

Типа я запускаю ./install.sh и эти команды выполняются автоматически без моего взаимодействия